# Update FK model DateField after save

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a person model and a group model, as shown below:

```
class Person (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  group = models.ForeignKey('Group', blank=True, null=True)

class Group (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_join = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
```

What I would like is when I add a new person to a group, the group's last_join is updated with the current time. Can I do this within the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use a [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/) on your Person model to update the time of Group. Auto_now is great for updating the last modified date, but that only applies to the model in which it's contained. It isn't aware of changes in state to other, related models.